# Allow me to dismiss the "notify others" pop up

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, stack-overflow-for-teams

Starting this morning, there is a huge pop up in the middle asking us to notify people. The pop up states:

> Increase the chances of getting an answer by notifing team members

[image]

but there's no way to dismiss it. I tried clicking all around it, but to no avail.

I can dismiss it only by notifying someone. Would it be possible to add an option to dismiss it, without notifying someone?

Comment: It seems they've also misspelled "notifying."

Comment: And on the 7th day Quality Assurance said: "It's fine"

Comment: This could be fixed. It would take from 6 to 8 weeks eventually.

Comment: At least there is an emoji in there, right? 

Comment: How is the party popper emoji relevant to the text? Throwing a party just to announce that you have posted a question seems a bit over the top.

Comment: @Turnip maybe the notification is as annoying as someone shooting a party popper in your face...

Comment: @LucaKiebel If you read the image post outside of the free hand red circle, it means: "YAY! We have fun and you did find a bug!  '

Comment: Congratulations! This was only a test, designed to make sure you were paying attention.

Comment: I no longer have faith in SO's front end team. Too many boondoggles over the past year.

Comment: At least the typo seems fixed by now...